# A problem on a sequential formulation for computing derivative

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, derivatives, convergence-divergence

**The Problem :** Let $J$ be an interval in $\mathbb{R}$. Let $f : J \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable. Let $x_n \leq c \leq y_n$ be such that $y_n - x_n \to 0$. To show that $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{f(y_n)-f(x_n)}{y_n-x_n}=f'(c)$$

**My Attempt :** Given $f$ is differentiable at $c$. Then the limit $\lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$ exists $($we denote it by $f'(c))$. Fix $\epsilon>0$. Then $\exists \delta>0$ such that
$$x \in (c-\delta,c+\delta) \cap J \setminus {c} \implies \left|\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}-f'(c)\right| < \epsilon \tag{1}$$ Fix this $\delta>0.$

Given the sequences $(x_n),(y_n)$ in $J$ with $y_n-x_n \to 0, \exists N_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq N_1 \implies |y_n-x_n| < \delta.$ Since $x_n \leq c \leq y_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N},$ max$\{|x_n-c|,|y_n-c|\} \leq |y_n-x_n|.$ Hence $n \geq N_1 \implies |x_n-c| < \delta, |y_n-c| < \delta.$ Then from $(1),$ we can say that $$n \geq N_1 \implies \left|\frac{f(x_n)-f(c)}{x_n-c}-f'(c)\right| < \epsilon, \,\, \,\, \left|\frac{f(y_n)-f(c)}{y_n-c}-f'(c)\right| < \epsilon$$

We need to show that $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$n \geq N \implies \left|\frac{f(y_n)-f(x_n)}{y_n-x_n}-f'(c)\right|<\epsilon$$

Am I in the right direction? If yes, how do I proceed from this point? If no, what should be the right direction? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Again!!! Do you live in "Long Long Island"? (Although you are nothing compare to your big bro!!!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right path to the solution.

Using your results and the triangle inequality, we have

$$
 \newcommand\eps\varepsilon
 | f(y_n)-f(x_n) - f'(c) ( y_n-x_n) |
 \leq | f(y_n)-f(c)-f'(c) (y_n-c) |
 + | f(x_n)-f(c)-f'(c) (x_n-c) |
 \\
 \leq \eps |y_n-c| + \eps| x_n-c|
 \leq 2\eps |y_n-x_n|
$$

Finally, divide by $|y_n-x_n|$.

Comment: That was smooth. Thank you!